# Finding Compatible Times Across Timezones

Tags: javascript, time

I'm working on a tournament feature where entrants provide a timezone and a preferred 12-hour window in which they'd like to play. Given that the clock goes 0-24, any two 12-hour windows will at least touch at the ends. I'm stuck on how to pinpoint a workable time given the ranges and UTC offsets for which those ranges are relevant.

Example:

- **Player A** - Offset: UTC+2 - Range: 0:00 - 12:00
- **Player B** - Offset: UTC-3 - Range: 9:00 - 21:00

How can I find the best possible time for a match *from both players' perspectives*? In a perfect scenario this would be square in the middle of each player's range but obviously that's not achievable in most cases.

Comment: "*Given that the clock goes 0-24, any two 12-hour windows will at least touch at the ends*" Not necessarily. Timezones range from -11 to +14, which is 25 hours. :-)

Comment: Does the match have an exact range? To make it easier, consider changing the given times to UCT.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to understand method of doing this is to figure out what time each player's range is in UTC, find the overlap, and then convert it back to the player's timezones.

```js
const players = [
  {
    offset: 2,
    start: 0,
    end: 12
  },
  {
    offset: -3
    start: 9,
    end: 21
  }
];

players.forEach(p => {
  p.rangeUtc = [p.start + p.offset, p.end + p.offset];
});

const overlapUtc = [Math.max(...players.map(p => p.rangeUtc[0])),
                    Math.min(...players.map(p => p.rangeUtc[1]))];

players.forEach(p => {
  p.overlapLocal = [overlapUtc[0] - p.offset, overlapUtc[1] - p.offset];
});
```

You're now left with the players' overlapping times stored in their local timezones as an array of `[startHour, endHour]` in their respective player objects.

I've made some assumptions about how you're storing the time data here, but you should be able to adapt it.

Answer (score -4):

I think you need the `Date()` command:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log("the date is: " + date.now.getDate());
console.log("the year is: " + date.now.getYear());
console.log("the time is: " + date.now.getTime());
console.log("the utc date is: " + date.now.getUTCDate());
```